# function sumArray(array, n)

Tags: javascript, array

por que me salta este error;

```
for (let i = 0; i < size; i++)
    > 93 |             const a = array[0];
         |             ^
      94 | 
      95 |         for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      96 |             if (i === j) continue;
```

este es mi codigo;
// La función llamada 'sumArray' recibe como argumento un arreglo de números ordenados llamado 'array' y un número
// entero llamdo 'n' y debe devolver true si alguna combinación de dos números cualesquiera del arreglo sumados
// dan n, y devuelva false si ninguna combinación de dos números sumados da como resultado el número n.

```
// Ej:
// sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13)  debería devolver true ya que 2 + 11 = 13
// sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 14)  debería devolver false ya que no es posible sumar 14 con dos números del arreglo
// Pista: Podes usar bucles/ciclos anidados
// Aclaración: No es válido sumar el mismo número dos veces
// Ej:
// sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 4)  Si bien 2 + 2 = 4 no está permitido sumar el mismo número dos veces
// por lo tanto también debería devolver false en este caso

// Tu código aca:


const sumArray = (array, n) => {
    const size = array.length;{

    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++)
        const a = array[0];}

    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if (i === j) continue;
        const b = array[j];
        if (a + b === n) { return true; }
    }
}

return false;
}
```

Comment: Tienes un error de tipeo, dejaste un `{` abierto en el lugar incorrecto. En la linea `const size = array.length;{` después del punto y coma tienes un `{`. Por lo demás tu función tiene otros problemas además del mencionado.

Comment: gracias, igual no encuentro el error

Comment: const sumArray = (array, numero) => {
        const size = array.length;

        for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) 
            const a = array[i];

            for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (i === j) continue;
                const b = array[j];
                if (a + b === numero) return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

esta es mi linea, me ayudas a ver los errores. saludos..

Answer (score 3):

Con la línea resultado podes agrupar todo tu desafío.

```js
let arreglo = [2,5,7,10,11,15,20];

function sumArray(numeros, ingreso){
    return numeros.some(numero => numeros.filter(n => n != numero).includes(ingreso-numero))
}

for (let i = 4; i < 25; i += 3) {
  console.log(`Para el número ${i}: ${sumArray(arreglo, i)}`)
}
```

**Explicación del código**

Utilizando la función [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), podemos lograr el desafío fácilmente, esta función devuelve true si al menos 1 condición se cumple. Esta condición se realiza con la ayuda de [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) e [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Con [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) se itera sobre el arreglo elemento por elemento, para después filtrar ese elemento de nuestro arreglo (se ignoran los números iguales a ese) con `filter(n => n != numero)` y finalmente con [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) se busca el complemento de la suma `(a + b = c) -> (a = c - b)`.

**Ejemplo**: si ingresamos 4

- `some` comienza con el 2

  - `filter` devuelve el arreglo sin el 2 --> `[5,7,10,11,15,20]`
  - En el anterior arreglo buscamos con `includes` el elemento 2 (4 - 2 = 2); Como no está en el array nos retorna `false`.
- Continua con el siguiente elemento y realiza las mismas operaciones hasta hallar una coincidencia o hasta terminar con el arreglo

**Ejemplo**: si ingresamos 13

- `some` comienza con el 2

  - `filter` devuelve el arreglo sin el 2 --> `[5,7,10,11,15,20]`
  - En el anterior arreglo buscamos con `includes` el elemento 11 (13 - 2 = 11); Como está en el arreglo nos retorna `true` y sale de la función.

Comment: Como comentario, siempre es bueno explicar la respuesta, en mi parecer, lo es más cuando la pregunta es de alguien que se nota que está aprendiendo a programar.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya te mencionaron en los comentarios, el problema con tu función es que los corchetes (`{`) no cierran de forma correcta. Por lo que la forma correcta es la siguiente:

```javascript
const sumArray = (array, numero) => {
  const size = array.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    const a = array[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      if (i === j) continue;
      const b = array[j];
      if (a + b === numero) return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Aparte podrías cambiar un poco la condición del segundo for para que sea más legible, el funcionamiento es el mismo y es más "fácil de leer".

```js
const sumArray = (array, numero) => {
  const size = array.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    const a = array[i];
    for (let j = i; j < size; j++) {
      if (i !== j) {
        const b = array[j];
        if (a + b === numero) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(sumArray([2, 5, 7, 10, 11, 15, 20], 13));
```

Comment: gracias a todos por la ayuda..

Answer (score 0):

```
const sumArray = (array, n) => {
    const size = array.length;
    let a, i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a = array[0];
    }

    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if (i === j) continue;
        const b = array[j];
        if (a + b === n) { return true; }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13));
console.log(sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 14));
```

El siguiente código al declararse const, sólo será posible acceder dentro de una sentencia.

```
const a = array[0];
```

El siguiente código tiene que ser declarado fuera del ciclo for ya que es utilizado posteriormente.

```
let a, i;
```

**OTRA FORMA**: Optimizando tu código

```
const sumArray2 = (array, n) => {
    const size = array.length,
        a = array[0];
    
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        const b = array[j];
        if (a + b === n) { return true; }
    }
    return false;
}
console.log(sumArray2([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13));
console.log(sumArray2([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 14));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola tengo una duda con este código.. Al declarar let a = array[0]; se quedara estático  con el numero [2] entonces ya no podría tomar el valor de los siguientes números del arreglo.   Ya no cumpliría la suma de recorrer cada numero y sumar con el resto...

me pueden apoyar si es correcta mi apreciación?

```
const sumArray2 = (array, n) => {
    const size = array.length,
        a = array[0];
    
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        const b = array[j];
        if (a + b === n) { return true; }
    }
    return false;
}
console.log(sumArray2([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13));
console.log(sumArray2([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 14));
```