# function suma de arrays

Tags: javascript

estoy realizando un test y tengo el siguiente ejercicio..

> La función llamada 'sumArray' recibe como argumento un arreglo de números ordenados llamado 'array' y un número entero llamdo 'n' y debe devolver `true` si alguna combinación de dos números cualesquiera del arreglo sumados dan 'n', y debe devolver `false` si ninguna combinación de dos números sumados da como resultado el número 'n'.
>
> Ej:
>
> ```
> sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 13)  // debería devolver true
>                                    // ya que 2 + 11 = 13
>
> sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 14)  // debería devolver false
>                                    // ya que no es posible
>                                    // sumar 14 con dos números del arreglo
> ```
>
> Pista: Puedes usar bucles/ciclos anidados
>
> Aclaración: No es válido sumar el mismo número dos veces
>
> Ej:
>
> ```
> sumArray([2,5,7,10,11,15,20], 4) // Si bien 2 + 2 = 4 no está
>                                  // permitido sumar el mismo 
>                                  // número dos veces por lo tanto
>                                  // también debería devolver false
> ```

Tengo esto de código escrito (a lo cual veo me parece bien). Pero el test me sigue tirando error. ¿Habrá otra forma de hacerlo? o ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal yo?

```js
const sumArray = (array, n) => {
  const size = array.length;
  {
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++)
      const a = array[0];
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      if (i === j) continue;
      const b = array[j];
      if (a + b === n) { return true; }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te *tira* el test?

Comment: Esta pregunta ya tiene una respuesta [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/463123/function-sumarrayarray-n)

Comment: Hola  ! si, encontré esa respuesta.. pero de todas formas o no lo comprendo o algo estoy haciendo mal...  pero no logro aprobar el test...

Comment: Si con ninguna de las respuestas de la pregunta original, logras aprobar el test, pon un comentario en cada respuesta, indicando los valores del `array` y el valor de `n` que hacen que el test falle. Si es así, podría revisar la pregunta original y dar una respuesta en ella. Saludos

Comment: El error porque `continue` se debe de usar cuando hay un `break` dentro de un bloque `while`. La solución a tu problema en otros términos sería usar [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) : `return array.some(e => array.some(a => e !== a && e + a === n))`